# Existe uma ferramenta para fazer teste de caixa preta em C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testes

Sei que o Java possui a IDE sikuli. O C# tem uma ferramenta semelhante?

Comment: Da uma olhada: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sikuli4net/

Comment: Qual tipo de sistema? web, desktop...

Comment: Eu gostaria de uma ferramenta que pudesse realizar o teste em um sistema desktop, mas seria interessante saber se existe uma ferramenta para web também.

Comment: E obrigado, Francisco. Era essa ferramenta mesmo que procurava para VS

Comment: Existe o Sikuli4net para o C#. Não sei se atende ao seu cenário.